# JQuery / JavaScript Keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a typing speed test with a textarea and I have I paragraph split into spans. Every time the user hits space, it highlights the next span. Then I split the textarea val() and compare the two at the end. I have everything working except I cannot get the enter key to do what I want it to do. I need it to act like the space bar(in the background) and act as the enter key on screen.

```
$(function() {

//APPEARANCE
$('#error').hide();
$('#oldTextOne').hide();
$('#oldTextTwo').hide();
$('#oldTextThree').hide();
$('#oldTextFour').hide();
$('#oldTextFive').hide();
$('.linkBox').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('linkBox').addClass('linkHover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('linkHover').addClass('linkBox');
});



//FUNCTIONALITY VARIABLES
var min = '5';
var sec = '00';
var realSec = 0;
var errorTest = "hasn't started yet";
var oldTextVal;
var para;

// PICK A RANDOM PARAGRAPH



function pickRandom() {

    var date = new Date();
    date = date.getTime();
    date += '';
    var dateSplit = date.split('');
    var temp = dateSplit.length - 1;
    var picker = dateSplit[temp];

    if (picker === '0' || picker === '1') {
        para = $('#oldTextOne').text();
    }

    else if (picker === '2' || picker === '3') {
        para = $('#oldTextTwo').text();
    }

    else if (picker === '4' || picker === '5') {
        para = $('#oldTextThree').text();
    }

    else if (picker === '6' || picker === '7') {
        para = $('#oldTextFour').text();
    }

    else {
        para = $('#oldTextFive').text();
    }

    var splitPara = para.split(' ');

    for (i in splitPara) {
        $('#oldTextBox').append('<span id="pw' + i + '">' + splitPara[i] + '</span> ');
    }

}

pickRandom();

//FUNCTION FOR TIMER

//APPEARANCE
function show() {
    $('#timer').text(min + ' : ' + sec);
}
show();

//COUNT-DOWN
var count = function() {
    sec = +sec - 1;
    sec += '';
    realSec++;

    if (+sec === -1) {
        sec = '59';
        min -= 1;
        min += '';
    }

    if (sec.length === 1) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
    }

    show();

    if (sec === '00' && min === '0') {
        clearInterval(run);
        checkIt();
    }

};

// TYPE THE TEXT INTO #TYPEDTEXTBOX

$('#pw0').addClass('green');
var lastLetter;

$('#typedTextBox').focus().keypress(function() {
    if (errorTest === "hasn't started yet") {
        errorTest = 'running';
        run = setInterval(count, 1000);
    }



//STOP ERRORS FROM PEOPLE HITTING SPACE BAR TWICE IN A ROW  !!NOT WORKING IN IE8
    var thisLetter = event.which;

    if (lastLetter === 32 && event.which === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    lastLetter = thisLetter;

}).keyup(function() {

//STOP ERRORS FROM BACKSPACE NOT REGISTERING WITH KEYPRESS FUNCTION
    if (event.which === 8) {
        lastLetter = 8;
    }

    if (event.which === 13) {

                ?????????????????????????????????????????????

    }


//SPLIT THE TYPED WORDS INTO AN ARRAY TO MATCH THE OLD TXT SPANS (TO HIGHLIGHT THE CURRENT WORD IN OLDTXT)
    var typedWords = $(this).val().split(' ');
    var temp = typedWords.length - 1;
    var oldTemp = temp - 1;
    var stopErrors = temp + 1;

    $('span:nth(' + temp + ')').addClass('green');
    $('span:nth(' + oldTemp + ')').removeClass('green');
    $('span:nth(' + stopErrors + ')').removeClass('green');

//SCROLL
    if (typedWords.length < 50) {
        return;
    }

    else if (typedWords.length > 50 && typedWords.length < 100) {
        $('#oldTextBox').scrollTop(30);
    }

    else if (typedWords.length > 100 && typedWords.length < 150) {
        $('#oldTextBox').scrollTop(60);
    }

    else if (typedWords.length > 150 && typedWords.length < 200) {
        $('#oldTextBox').scrollTop(90);
    }

    else if (typedWords.length > 200) {
        $('#oldTextBox').scrollTop(120);
    }

//KEEP FOCUS IN THE TYPING AREA
}).blur(function() {
    if (errorTest !== 'done') {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});

//COMPARE
//MAKE AN ARRAY OF THE OLDTEXT

var oldWords = para.split(' ');

//FUNCTION TO DISPLAY RESULTS

var checkIt = function() {
    errorTest = 'done';
    var correct = 0;
    var typed = $('#typedTextBox').val();
    var typedWords = typed.split(' ');
    $('#typedTextBox').blur();

    for (i = 0; i < typedWords.length; i++) { 
        if (typedWords[i] === oldWords[i]) {
            correct += 1;
        }
    }

    var errors = typedWords.length - correct;
    var epm = (errors / realSec) * 60;
    var wpm = Math.round(( ($('#typedTextBox').val().length / 5 ) / realSec ) * 60);
    var realWpm = Math.round(wpm - epm); 


//SHOW RESULTS

    $('#oldTextBox').html('<br><span id="finalOne">WPM : <strong>' + realWpm + ' </strong></span><span class="small">(error adjusted)</span><br><br><span id="finalTwo">You made ' + errors + ' errors </span><br><span id="finalThree">Total character count of ' + $('#typedTextBox').val().length + '</span><br><span id="finalFour">Gross WPM : ' + wpm + '</span>');
};

//STOP BUTTON APPEARANCE AND FUNCTIONALITY

$('#stop').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('stopHover');

    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('stopHover');

    }).click(function() {

    if (errorTest === 'running') {
        checkIt();
        clearInterval(run);
        errorTest = 'done';
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Just fyi, I did define lastLetter earlier in $(function

Comment: Can you post all of your code or make a simplified JSFiddle demo?

Comment: Posted entire code now, I'm new so don't yell at me too much

Comment: But any tips or hints would be appreciated

Comment: @user3547823 It's ok...this might take a bit.  People will be working out solutions and this is one of those 'unusual specific requests' that take some time to work out. You'll get alerted when an answer comes.

Comment: and there is a new answer for you now :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//ENTER KEY
    if (event.which === 13) {
        //event.stopPropagation(); or
        event.preventDefault();
        //simulate spacebar
        $(window).trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 32, keyCode: 32});
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, but I'm going to start reading up on stopPropogation.

Comment: see my update in my answer, basically try: event.preventDefault(); instead of stopPropagation();

Comment: well, I'm not getting this to work, It seems that preventDefault isn't going to be the right way because I still need the enter button to work in the textarea. But I don't know how to test the window.trigger. All I know is that it is returning an object but I haven't been able to get it to actually change my highlighted span (like the spacebar does).

Answer (score 0):

@james - Thanks for the help. I found a better way of thinking about the problem. Instead of changing the enter key action, I changed the split function to var typedWords = typed.split(/[ \r\n]+/);